# Error in StartActivity Android

Tags: java, android, android-activity

my code below is crashing. I am trying to have an app where the user inputs a word in the EditText and, after clicking the button, the app checks if the inputed word equals "hello", and if it does, the app takes the user to another activity.

The error is:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method toHi (MainActivity)(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'button'

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.reynaldo.myapplication.MainActivity">

<Button
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:onClick="toHi (MainActivity)" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="hi"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void toHi (View v){
    EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text);
    String key = text.getText().toString();
    if (key.equals("hello")){
        Intent i = new Intent (this, Main2Activity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: One of options is using `setTag(your_value)` and `getTag()` to save the state of views

Comment: so if I have a textView object tv that I want to strike/unstrike, I would write something like: if (tv.getTag() == False) {tv.setTag(1);}? What argument does setTag take?

Comment: You can use any thing, `true` and `false` are good for your purpose.

Comment: When I write first comment the question was about saving state of view that it's striked or not, now I saw it's changed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the value of `onClick`:

replace

```
android:onClick="toHi (MainActivity)"
```

with

```
android:onClick="toHi"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your event specified in Button onClick is "toHi (MainActivity)" while you are defining method public void toHi(View view).
One thing more,there are circular dependencies in your xml file.You are specifiying layout_below in both button and edit text.

Code like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    >

    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text" //Specify this here only
        android:onClick="toHi" />  // Change here

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="hi"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```